# How can I create a combination/permutation of words in a trie from a character array?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation, trie

I have a trie that contains multiple words in it. I am attempting to create a permutation/combination of all possible words that can be found in the dictionary from an array of characters without repeats of letters in the char array. I have tried to research ideas/starting point but all the possible solutions I have found are allowing repeats, which is not what I want.

For example:

Suppose I have the words {tiptoe, top, tuple, put, pups, pop, putt } in the trie and I have the char array that contains:
 [t, i, p, u, l, o, e, s].

The output should be:

- top
- tuple
- put

Can someone please help me out with starting this algorithm?

Comment: You can do a simple recursive backtracking to generate all the possible words from the char array and on each step to check whether they are part of the trie.

Comment: If you can traverse the trie, I would do the opposite: take all words from the trie and see if they can be formed from the char array. The complexity of that would be (in general) much less.

Comment: Otherwise, you could try all letters at the trie level 1, for each letter try the n-1 remaining letters at level 2 etc... (a recursive function should help). The complexity will still be better than factorial from all combinations of the array.

Comment: @RingØ, the 'opposite' approach is a very nice idea :)

Comment: @RingØ Even if the trie has over 20,000 words would the runtime be faster than any of the other options?

Comment: Usually yes. Except when the char array is small (and/or the list of words is gigantic).

Comment: @RingØ Thanks for the suggestions. I attempted your second suggestion and I got something that worked perfectly for what I needed! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Welcome to the CS world :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. iterate char array 
   1.a pick first char
   1.b iterate word array 
    1.b.A mark all chars in all words(only first match in a word) in word array if picked char is match with those chars.
2. Those words having all chars are marked are the output

Example first iteration:

```
char from char array = t;
chars marked in word array : {t`iptoe, t`op, t`uple, put`, pups, pop, put`t }
```